# ErlangC Function Application Error - TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
  RateService   Cashiers
0   19.8           1    
1   19.8           1    
2   19.8           1    
3   19.8           1    
4   19.8           1    
5   19.8           1    
6   19.8           1    
7   19.8           1    
8   19.8           1    
9   19.8           1    
10  19.8           1    
11  19.8           1    
12  19.8           1    
13  19.8           1    
14  19.8           1    
15  19.8           1    
16  19.8           1    
17  19.8           1    
18  19.8           1    
19  19.8           1    
20  19.8           1    
21  19.8           1    
22  19.8           1    
23  19.8           1
```

I would like to create a new column where the following ErlangC function applies:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
def ErlangC(k, r):
    
    H = np.array(list(r))
    I = np.array(list(k))
    A = np.power(I,H)
    B = factorial(H)
    C = np.subtract(H,I)
    D = np.divide(H,C)
    E = np.divide(A,B)
    L = E * D
    sum_ = 0
    for i in H:
        F = np.power(k,i)
        sum_ += F / factorial(i)
    return (L / (sum_ + L))
```

So I am invoking the function

```
df['C(k,r)'] = df.apply(lambda x: ErlangC(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```

El error me lo marca en la siguiente línea:

```
 2 def ErlangC(k, r):
      3 
----> 4     H = np.array(list(r))
      5     I = np.array(list(k))
      6     A = np.power(I,H)
```

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Maybe I am applying the list wrong when integrating it to an array but if I delete it I would have a 0-d array error. Any suggestion?

Comment: You cant `list(numeric)`. You're trying to do `list(1)`, which isn't allowed

Comment: Hi, you may want to avoid the factorials, since they grow very fast and leads to numerical unnaccuracy or for large enough numbers, it might not be computed, instead I'd suggest you to use ErlangB and then use its results to use to feed ErlangC. Or you can use [pyworkforce](https://pypi.org/project/pyworkforce/) which already has this implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `[]` to create list from scalar.

```py
    H = np.array([r])
    I = np.array([k])
```

Comment: Thanks, the result gives me a list [] in the column but I adjust it. It was a conceptual error on my part, thanks for correcting me.